# Required reputation for direct tag wiki edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, editing-help

I recently noticed that *non-trusted* users cannot directly edit tag wikis, even
when they surpass the required reputation threshold for expanded editing
privileges. Their edits still have to go through a peer-review process.

There is probably at least one good reason for this decision (e.g. to avoid vandalism), but I am still curious about the rationale? After all, *established users* with more than 2000 reputation can edit any question and answer on Stack Overflow, and have their edits applied immediately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tag edits affect all users who use the tag and all existing questions that use the tag. Editing a post is something that happens on a post-by-post basis, but tag edits, when made/approved, are way more far-reaching in impact. Imagine if a 2k user suddenly decided that [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) should be the tag for Crystal Skull Seekers instead of Cascading Style Sheets, and made such a change? All of a sudden there are tens of thousands or hundreds of thousands of questions improperly tagged.

In short, it's too easy to get 2k reputation and be guaranteed the level of trust to unilaterally affect potentially tens of thousands of posts (or more). Such a privilege is—and should be—reserved for people who have earned much more trust.

It also takes quite a while (not counting bounties or accepted answer bonuses) to earn 20,000 reputation: at least 200 days on the site, typically much more than that. A similarly prolific person would earn 2,000 reputation in just 3 weeks. Would you want someone who has been a member of the site for only 3 weeks to be able to edit tag wikis unilaterally? I wouldn't.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I hope not... that movie was quite a bummer.

Comment: [Cansei de Ser Sexy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cansei_de_Ser_Sexy) is what I want it to mean :)